# Ошибка с модулем python-docx: docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'test.docx'

Tags: python, python-docx

Код:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:/Python/docx/test2.py", line 2, in <module>
>         doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
>     File "E:\Программы\Python\lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 25, in Document
>         document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
>     File "E:\Программы\Python\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 116, in open
>         pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
>     File "E:\Программы\Python\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_file
>         phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
>     File "E:\Программы\Python\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 31, in __new__
>        "Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file
> docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'test.docx'
> ```

Comment: Файл 'test.docx' находиться в директории /docx

Comment: А у вас точно файл в docx формате, а не переименованный doc?

Comment: `doc = docx.Document('docx/test.docx')?` А так, ошибка произошла тут https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/opc/phys_pkg.py#L24 там видно какие проверки путь с файлом не прошли

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю что уже поздно отвечать конкретно вам, но для тех, кто будет сталкиваться с такой же проблемой - у вас в проводнике должны быть видны расширения файлов, в случае если эта галочка не стоит - возникает ошибка. Сам несколько часов провозился с этим, в итоге нашел такое решение.

Comment: Это не должно никак влиять, это влияет чисто на отображение, но не на фактическое имя файла (под которым файл доступен программно). Скорее всего проблема у вас была в чем-то другом.

Comment: Разве что вы имя файла в программе указывали без расширения - так не находило, потом включили отображение расширения, скопировали с расширением - после этого нашло. Но это проблема не в галочке, а в том что указывать имя нужно с расширением.

Comment: Не должно, но похоже влияет

Comment: А вы отключите теперь отображение расширения и проверьте еще раз. Скорее всего не перестанет работать.

Comment: Действительно, все еще работает, но я точно уверен что указал формат файла в пути и ничего не переименовывал...

Comment: Значит проблема не решается галкой (развожу руками)